# How to copy class object data to edmx object in c#

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, edmx

I am working in MVC. The user will enter data for about 50 fields, I will get this data in a class object from the view.

So, how can I copy this class object to an edmx table object in order save data into data base in c# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding http://automapper.org/ in your project and in your code you would write something like.

```
var address = Mapper.Map<Address>(yourViewModel);
   ......................
   .......................
```

Comment: Thank you so much. its working & you saved my time as well as helped me in learning new concept....